# How to provide callback url for a server in an Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, oauth-2.0, callback

There is a oauth2 server that I want to use to authenticate my app.

I know *what* is supposed to happen. I want to start an activity that opens the browser or has a webview with the url to the login website. 
However, in that url I have to set the callback uri of my app, so that the oauth2 server can answer.

I already know that I have to add this to my activity in the androidmanifest to receive a callback:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="oauth-testing" />
</intent-filter>
```

And I also know that I have to call the activity containing the login website like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://someOAuthServer.com?redirect_uri=oauth-testing://UNKNOWN"));
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

And that's the Part I don't get yet. I understand that the oauth server takes the callback uri from the url parameter `redirect_uri` and I understand that `oauth-testing` tells my device/app which activity recieves the callback. However, I don't quite know what "url" I'm supposed to pass where `UNKNOWN`stands in the example above.

Do I have to set my own IP? If yes, which one? A device can have more than one IP. Does it matter? I've seen one approach that did this: "oauth-testing:///". They just put three forward slashes. What exactly does that do? Is this even valid?

When I try to go with "oauth-testing:///" then I receive a callback when I "return" to my activity via the navigation bar "back" button. However, it does obviously not hold any data.

Is my approach wrong? Do I even need to call `startActivityForResult`or will that send mixed signals to my activity?

### Update

I've just found out that "https:///" == "https://localhost". So, that's obviously wrong. The last thing I can think of is sending my IP in that url. But how? And which one?

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to integrate the [Google AppAuth Library](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) to handle logins for you, which follows the latest security recommendations.

They have a sample that you can run - if you can get that working you should then be able to apply the same principles to your own app.

PS. There are some notes on a blog of mine on [How to run the Android AppAuth Code Sample](https://authguidance.com/2018/02/20/android-setup/).